# What does "dror out" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "dror out" mean in the following passage? Wells's short story Mr. Brisher's Treasure

> But in the afternoon I got easier in my mind—it seemed to me it must 'ave been there so long it was pretty sure to stop a bit longer—and I tried to get up a bit of a discussion to **dror out** the old man and see what 'e thought of treasure trove.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is phonetic spelling intended to convey the speaker’s accent. It means “draw out,” which means luring the man to join them.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think on "ar-ever"? I guess I don't have to ask a separate question for that. "Ar-ever—after all that was over, off I set for London..."

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev - **however**

Comment: in particular, this spelling shows an "intrusive r", something now pretty universal in non-rhotic British accents, but which was presumably still viewed as non-standard in Wells' day. An intrusive r in however is not common in any British dialect I know of today although I could see it coming about from a Cockney pronunciation of "how" as /hæə/ with the word treated as a transparent compound of the components "how" and "ever" rather than as a single word (as it is usually pronounced today)

Comment: I think that to "draw out the old man" is not to lure him to join them, it is to encourage him to speak about what he knows, to reveal his private knowledge.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Yes - that's confirmed by the way it's used again [later on in the text](https://americanliterature.com/author/hg-wells/short-story/mr-brishers-treasure).

Comment: @Tristan I think you also find it in some US southern accents.

Comment: [how] and [ar] - for someone from europe, these 2 prefixes sound so much apart from each other that i can barely imagine anybody talking like that.

Comment: Mostly that's an issue of spelling. Once you bear in mind their normative pronunciations /aʊ/ and /ɑː(ɹ)/ they look less far apart, even less far apart once you notice that non-rhotic varieties realise coda r as [ə̯] after lots of vowels (cf Standard German's realisation of coda r as [ɐ̯]). At that point, you basically just need the [ʊ] to centralise a little before it'll start being perceived by non-rhotic British speakers as some sort of "ar"

Comment: @Barmar It's also heard occasionally in some northern east coast US accents.

Comment: @clockw0rk & Tristan - this is 1890s London. Accents change, and phonetic representations are very clumsy at best.